# What does my instructor mean by declare each of the variables marked with "**" in the appropriate scope and using the appropriate type

Tags: javascript

I'm really lost and just don't understand what I'm supposed to be doing here. The way my brain works I need some examples. I don't want the answers. everything I've read just isn't clicking.

The whole //declare each of the variables marked with "**" in the appropriate scope and using the appropriate type. Just doesn't work out in my head and I cant find any examples of this. Usually pretty good at finding what I need here.

```js
// declare each of the variables marked with "**" in the appropriate scope and using the appropriate type

// create an event listener that calls the curveGrade() function when the Curve It!! button is clicked

// create an event listener that resets the scores and grades to their defaults when the Reset button is clicked

function applyBell(grade, index, ary) {
    switch (true) {
        case grade >= (mean + (gradeSlice * 2)): 
            ary[index] = 'A'
            break
        case grade >= (mean + gradeSlice):  
            ary[index] = 'B'
            break
        case grade >= (mean):
            ary[index] = 'C'
            break
        case grade >= (mean - gradeSlice): 
            ary[index] = 'D'
            break
        default:
            ary[index] = 'F'
            break
    }
}

function convertArray(obj) {
    ary = obj.value.split(',')
    ary = ary.map(function (x) {
        return parseInt(x)
    })
    return ary
}

// Condense the number of lines within the curveGrade() function as much as possible by converting 
// the functions to arrow functions. You can also condense the number of lines by combining some 
// separate lines of code into single lines. It currently has 18 lines of code. Without counting  
// empty lines, can you get the number of lines down to 8?

function curveGrades() {
    **sum = function (accumulator, currentValue) {
        return accumulator + currentValue
    }

    **sumGrades = function(array) {
        return array.reduce(sum)
    }

    **aryGrades = convertArray(document.querySelector('#scores'))

    **minGrade = aryGrades.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return Math.min(a, b)
    })
    
    **maxGrade = aryGrades.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return Math.max(a, b)
    })
    
    **mean = sumGrades(aryGrades) / aryGrades.length

    **range = maxGrade - minGrade

    gradeSlice = range / 5

    aryGrades.forEach(applyBell)

    // write the value of aryGrades to the grades div in the HTML document
}
```

Lost student in search of help!

```js
// declare each of the variables marked with "**" in the appropriate scope and using the appropriate type

// create an event listener that calls the curveGrade() function when the Curve It!! button is clicked

// create an event listener that resets the scores and grades to their defaults when the Reset button is clicked

curveIt = document.getElementById("submit")
curveIt.addEventListener("click", curveGrades)
output = document.getElementById("grades")

function applyBell(grade, index, ary) {
    switch (true) {
        case grade >= (mean + (gradeSlice * 2)): 
            ary[index] = 'A'
            break
        case grade >= (mean + gradeSlice):  
            ary[index] = 'B'
            break
        case grade >= (mean):
            ary[index] = 'C'
            break
        case grade >= (mean - gradeSlice): 
            ary[index] = 'D'
            break
        default:
            ary[index] = 'F'
            break
    }
}

function convertArray(obj) {
    ary = obj.value.split(',')
    ary = ary.map(function (x) {
        return parseInt(x)
    })
    return ary
}

// Condense the number of lines within the curveGrade() function as much as possible by converting 
// the functions to arrow functions. You can also condense the number of lines by combining some 
// separate lines of code into single lines. It currently has 18 lines of code. Without counting  
// empty lines, can you get the number of lines down to 8?

 function curveGrades() {
    let sum = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue

    let sumGrades = array => array.reduce(sum)

    const aryGrades = convertArray(document.querySelector('#scores'))

    var minGrade = aryGrades.reduce((a, b) => Math.min(a, b))
    
    var maxGrade = aryGrades.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b))
    
    mean = sumGrades(aryGrades) / aryGrades.length

    var range = maxGrade - minGrade

    gradeSlice = range / 5

    aryGrades.forEach(applyBell)

    output.innerHTML=aryGrades

    // write the value of aryGrades to the grades div in the HTML document
}
```

Well i gave it a good edit. I think i got it figured out but not sure where the reduction can be to get it to 8 or if i got any of the scope things right

Comment: The code uses various variables but never formally declares them. You are being asked to determine where the best location in the code would be to declare each (scope) and to determine what the best initial value (type) would be for each.

Comment: Right now they are in the window scope because they do not have var, let or const - same for gradeSlice and ary in the other function

Comment: i gave it an edit not sure if i did that right

Comment: Good edit - I think you've got the hang of it now. Guess you need to try reducing the number of lines further, eh? Here's a hint: If I have an array of numbers (say `aryNum`) and I need to find the maximum & minimum and then difference between those - I can do that simply by: `const diffMaxMin = Math.max(...aryNum) - ________;` The `...` allows one to apply `Math.max()` without `.reduce()`. Fill-up the blank & see if this is helpful with any `range` calculation in your quesiton. :-) **NOTE:** Please avoid using `var` in favor of `let` and `const`, unless there is a contextual necessity.

Comment: Awesome! huge help! thanks everyone.

Comment: Still missing a let in `function convertArray(obj) {
    ary = obj.value.split(',')` which can be written without it: `const convertArray = obj => obj.value.split(',').map(str => parseInt(str));` - note neither your nor my function tests the obj.value to exist or contain a string